# Minecraft 2.0-How Do I Turn Super Hostile Mode Off?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering: how do I turn Super Hostile Mode off in Minecraft 2.0? I have tried many things, such as doing `/weather clear 1000000` which was supposed to make the weather be clear for 1,000,000 seconds, but it didn't. Can you please help me out? I can't get OptiFine for 2.0 since it's just an April Fools joke, and it's lagging way too much when lightning strikes on Minecraft. I even tried turning it on Peaceful, but that only makes it so no monsters spawn in it, and it doesn't turn the lighting off. Please tell me how to turn this off as it is very annoying. I even tried making a new world, but there's no difference.

Comment: Minecraft 2.0 was an April Fool's joke, so I'm confused why you're still bothering with it, given the redstone bugs and whatnot...

Comment: @Unionhawk Agreed. Those redstone bugs are annoying. Even SethBling agrees.

Answer (score 2):

Super-hostile mode is hardcoded in Red and Purple. Use the Blue version instead.

Comment: @Alvin Not a typo. Super-hostile is not a mode, because "modes" means things that can be turned on and off. The **mobs** in Red and Purple are just always super-hostile—there is no mode to change. Like I said, it's hard-coded.

Comment: "Added new Super Hostile game **mode**, for a much more challenging Survival experience." as stated [here](http://mojang.com/2013/04/its-finally-coming-minecraft-2-0/) (Also, the mode is not only about the mods, but also the lightning.)

Comment: @Alvin Ah, I didn't know it also changed the lighting. Still misnamed since it can't be turned off, but I suppose we have to use the words they use even if they're inaccurate.